# Using Three20 TTPhotoViewController with MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, three20, ttphotoviewcontroller

I'm trying to use the Three20 TTPhotoViewController with MonoTouch.  I've derived FacebookPhoto from TTPhoto and FacebookPhotoSource from TTPhotoSource and am now trying to invoke the TTPhotoViewController but I get the following exception when pushing the view controller:

> Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: *** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:]: nil argument

I noticed that the monotouch bindings in this github project: https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/492f68c3c2007f0638452cc8a5a762556db224ba/Three20/binding were missing the photoAtIndex binding, so I added that and recompiled them, but I haven't been able to figure out why I am getting this exception.

Here is how I'm invoking the TTPhotoViewController:

```
List<Photo> photoList = FacebookGraphApi.Instance.GetAlbumPhotos(album.id);
List<FacebookPhoto> fbPhotoList = photoList.Select(x => new FacebookPhoto(x)).ToList();
var photos = new TTPhotoViewController();
photos.PhotoSource = new FacebookPhotoSource(fbPhotoList);
NavController.PushViewController(photos, true);
```

Here is the definition of the TTPhotoSource

```
    class FacebookPhotoSource : TTPhotoSource
    {
        List<FacebookPhoto> _photoList;

        public FacebookPhotoSource (List<FacebookPhoto> photoList)
        {
            _photoList = photoList;
            int i = 0;
            foreach (FacebookPhoto photo in photoList) {
                photo.PhotoSource = this;
                photo.Index = i++;
            }
        }

        public override string Title {
            get {
                return "Facebook Photos";
            }
            set  {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public override int NumberOfPhotos {
            get {
                return _photoList.Count;
            }
        }

        public override int MaxPhotoIndex {
            get {
                return _photoList.Count -1;
            }
        }

        public override TTPhoto PhotoAtIndex(int photoIndex)
        {
            return _photoList[photoIndex];
        }

    }
```

and here is the definition of the FacebookPhoto:

```
    class FacebookPhoto : TTPhoto
    {
        Photo _photo;
        public FacebookPhoto(Photo photo)
        {
            _photo = photo;
        }

        public override string Caption {
            get {
                if(_photo.name == null)
                    return "";
                return _photo.name;
            }
            set {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public override TTPhotoSource PhotoSource { get; set; }

        public override int Index { get; set; }

        public override SizeF Size {
            get {
                return new SizeF(_photo.width, _photo.height);
            }
            set {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public override string URLForVersion (int version)
        {
            switch (version) {
            case 4:
                return _photo.picture;
            default:
                return _photo.source;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just my two cents: stay away from Three20. It's outdated, documentation sucks, and will give you more headache than the amount of work it saves.

IMHO it's not worth it.

(I have worked with it in the past)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, after fighting with it for more hours than I want to admit, I am coming to the same conclusion.

Comment: I dealt with a legacy project embedded in three20, I found it much simpler to start from scratch and pick and choose code to reuse when developing again. If you can, get rid of it. If its a huge project where starting from scratch isn't an option... You gotta do what you gotta do...